# Cascading menu using divs

Tags: html, css

I am going to create a cascading menu with `div`s, for example when an `<a>` hovered another div shows:

I can create it with `li` and `ul` but want to do it with `div`.

**My problem:** When mouse pointer is on `<a>` the `div` shows but when mouse pointer come to `div`, `div` will disappear (`display:none;`)

[this is my demo](http://jsfiddle.net/koolbalik/8xT4H/1/)

```
<div id="topDiv">
<img src="http://www.balit.ir/kgl/pic/user/logo.png" id="logo"/>
<div id="rightTopMenu">
   <a href="about.html">About KGL
    <div class="hoverMenuDiv">
        <a href="#">About Samuel</a>
        <a href="#">About Hoshange</a>
        <a href="#">About GhochAli</a>
    </div>
   </a> 
   <a href="Contact.html">Contact KGL</a>
   <a href="http://www.balit.ir/kgl">KGL Website</a>
   <a href="#">KGL Gallery</a>
</div>
```

My CSS:

```
    body{
    margin:0;
}

#topDiv{
    position:absolute;
    background: black;
}

#logo{
    width:65px;
    height:auto;
    margin-left:40px;
}

#rightTopMenu{
    float:right;
    margin-top:20px;
}

#rightTopMenu a{
    position:relative;
   color: white;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration:none;
    width: 103px;
}

.hoverMenuDiv{
    position:absolute;
    top:40px;
    background:#CAD20E;
    display:none;
    text-align:center;
    width:130px;
}

#rightTopMenu a:hover, #rightTopMenu a:focus{
    color:#CAD20E;
}

#rightTopMenu a:hover+.hoverMenuDiv{
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: Just so you know, it's `div`, not `dive`. :)

Comment: @BeatAlex Yes I know, what is my answer

Comment: you can't nest <a>'s within <a>'s.  You need to use a different div structure in the nav.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2rtUW/)**

In your CSS, you need

```
.hoverMenuDiv:hover{
    display:block;
}
```

This ensures that when you hover over the `div`, it will stay there.

Also, in my JSFiddle, I've put your HTML to this:

```
<a href="about.html">About KGL</a> 
<div class="hoverMenuDiv">
  <a href="#">About Samuel</a>
  <a href="#">About Hoshange</a>
  <a href="#">About GhochAli</a>
</div>
```

You can't have `<a>` tags in `<a>`'s.

Here is a second [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/2rtUW/1/) with the previous work done, but also deleting `top` in `.hoverMenuTop`. I think it looks better this way and behaves how most websites would.

Comment: i was speaking politely. and Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You have to add this when the user is inside menu.

```
.hoverMenuDiv:hover{
    display:block;
}
```

also remove `top` from this class `.hoverMenuDiv`

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/8xT4H/3/)

Answer (score 0):

This selector is too broad. It is targeting ALL of your anchors.

```
#rightTopMenu a { ... }
```

You need to only select the immediate child:

```
#rightTopMenu > a {
```

Also, consider using an unordered list as your menu container, not nested A-tags.

See: http://www.dhtmlgoodies.com/?whichScript=dhtmlgoodies_menu3

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the '>' selector instead of the '+' selector, like this:

```
#rightTopMenu:hover>.hoverMenuDiv{
    display:block;
}
```

The '+' selector is used for finding subsequent tags, but .hoverMenuDiv is actually a *child* tag of #rightTopMenu.

See [w3 schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) for a quick reference on this.